# Parsing a poorly constructed XML file in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I refer to the XML file as poorly constructed due to the fact that everything I want to get to is all stored across several elements which are all named "data" instead of having appropriately named elements.  This XML is returned from an API call of a program I'm integrating with (GoldMine CRM), so I can not influence how this XML would be constructed.

Here is the XML:

```
<GMAPI call="GetActiveWindowsList">
  <status code="1">Success</status>
  <data name="WindowsList">
    <data name="window">
      <data name="hWnd">2952796</data>
      <data name="WindowName">DIALOGSCHEDULEDEFAULT</data>
      <data name="WindowInternalName">DIALOG: 7220</data>
      <data name="Caption">Schedule a Next Action</data>
      <data name="WindowRect">
        <data name="Left">1032</data>
        <data name="Right">1550</data>
        <data name="Bottom">727</data>
        <data name="Top">177</data>
      </data>
      <data name="ClientRect">
        <data name="Left">1035</data>
        <data name="Right">1547</data>
        <data name="Bottom">724</data>
        <data name="Top">202</data>
      </data>
      <data name="Controls">
        <data name="#32770">
          <data name="Enabled">1</data>
          <data name="Visible">1</data>
          <data name="ParentID">2952796</data>
          <data name="hWnd">5574210</data>
          <data name="ID">0</data>
          <data name="Text">Detail</data>
          <data name="Controls">
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3083840</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3345982</data>
              <data name="ID">1022</data>
              <data name="Text">Lin&amp;k to selected Contact:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Edit">
              <data name="Enabled">0</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3411510</data>
              <data name="ID">104</data>
              <data name="Text">Bea Defkow</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Button">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">4460084</data>
              <data name="ID">1047</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Button">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3149362</data>
              <data name="ID">52325</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">2952750</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text">&amp;Reference:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="F2Edit">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">4001322</data>
              <data name="ID">1016</data>
              <data name="Text">CR</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">4457274</data>
              <data name="ID">99</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">4197926</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text">&amp;Notes:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="GM_CAL_HTML_EDIT_CTRL">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">5246490</data>
              <data name="ID">1017</data>
              <data name="Text">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"&gt;
&lt;HTML&gt;&lt;HEAD&gt;
&lt;STYLE type=text/css&gt; P, UL, OL, DL, DIR, MENU, PRE { margin: 0 auto;}&lt;/STYLE&gt;

&lt;META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 11.00.9600.17041"&gt;&lt;/HEAD&gt;&lt;BODY leftMargin=1 rightMargin=1 topMargin=1&gt;&lt;FONT size=2 face="Segoe UI"&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;CN&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/BODY&gt;&lt;/HTML&gt;</data>
              <data name="Controls">
                <data name="ToolbarWindow32">
                  <data name="Enabled">1</data>
                  <data name="Visible">1</data>
                  <data name="ParentID">5246490</data>
                  <data name="hWnd">4066838</data>
                  <data name="ID">1002</data>
                </data>
                <data name="ATL:01A98E08">
                  <data name="Enabled">1</data>
                  <data name="Visible">1</data>
                  <data name="ParentID">5246490</data>
                  <data name="hWnd">3214868</data>
                  <data name="ID">1001</data>
                  <data name="Controls">
                    <data name="Shell Embedding">
                      <data name="Enabled">1</data>
                      <data name="Visible">1</data>
                      <data name="ParentID">3214868</data>
                      <data name="hWnd">3018258</data>
                      <data name="ID">0</data>
                      <data name="Controls">
                        <data name="Shell DocObject View">
                          <data name="Enabled">1</data>
                          <data name="Visible">1</data>
                          <data name="ParentID">3018258</data>
                          <data name="hWnd">3018254</data>
                          <data name="ID">0</data>
                          <data name="Controls">
                            <data name="Internet Explorer_Server">
                              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
                              <data name="Visible">1</data>
                              <data name="ParentID">3018254</data>
                              <data name="hWnd">3018252</data>
                              <data name="ID">0</data>
                            </data>
                          </data>
                        </data>
                      </data>
                    </data>
                  </data>
                </data>
              </data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3018250</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text"> Options </data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3018232</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text">Acti&amp;vity:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="ComboBox">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3280372</data>
              <data name="ID">1039</data>
              <data name="Text">Next Actn</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3280368</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text">Cod&amp;e:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="F2Edit">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">5246436</data>
              <data name="ID">1012</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">454363506</data>
              <data name="ID">99</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3411422</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text">C&amp;olor:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="ComboBox">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3411394</data>
              <data name="ID">1037</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3411314</data>
              <data name="ID">291</data>
              <data name="Text">Opportunity / &amp;Project:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="ComboBox">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3411312</data>
              <data name="ID">1040</data>
              <data name="Text">(none)</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Button">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3542370</data>
              <data name="ID">2010</data>
              <data name="Text">New</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">20778328</data>
              <data name="ID">292</data>
              <data name="Text">Or Case:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="ComboBox">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3476822</data>
              <data name="ID">52168</data>
              <data name="Text">(none)</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Button">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3345734</data>
              <data name="ID">2011</data>
              <data name="Text">New</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3345724</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text">Primary &amp;User:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="ComboBox">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3345718</data>
              <data name="ID">1011</data>
              <data name="Text">RICK ()</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3345710</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text"> Time </data>
            </data>
            <data name="Button">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">0</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3345708</data>
              <data name="ID">2067</data>
              <data name="Text">Recurring...</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">53742874</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text">&amp;Date:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="DateEdit">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">4787478</data>
              <data name="ID">1013</data>
              <data name="Text">6/25/2014</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">1442624</data>
              <data name="ID">99</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">5311752</data>
              <data name="ID">101</data>
              <data name="Text">Ti&amp;me:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="TimeEdit">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">5442822</data>
              <data name="ID">1014</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">5899074</data>
              <data name="ID">99</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">42142960</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text">Durat&amp;ion:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Edit">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">6032574</data>
              <data name="ID">1018</data>
              <data name="Text">0</data>
            </data>
            <data name="msctls_updown32">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">3214524</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
            </data>
            <data name="ComboBox">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">5246130</data>
              <data name="ID">1036</data>
              <data name="Text">Min  </data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">8457380</data>
              <data name="ID">1023</data>
              <data name="Text">A&amp;larm:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="TimeEdit">
              <data name="Enabled">0</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">54725774</data>
              <data name="ID">1032</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">5443466</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text">On:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="DateEdit">
              <data name="Enabled">0</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">40765854</data>
              <data name="ID">1033</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">1508158</data>
              <data name="ID">-1</data>
              <data name="Text">Actions</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">1311400</data>
              <data name="ID">1038</data>
              <data name="Text">Noti&amp;fy via E-mail</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">6423206</data>
              <data name="ID">1024</data>
              <data name="Text">Auto-generate R&amp;SVP</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">44630312</data>
              <data name="ID">1034</data>
              <data name="Text">Mark as Priv&amp;ate</data>
            </data>
            <data name="CheckBoxButton">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">6362818</data>
              <data name="ID">1001</data>
              <data name="Text">Send a request wit&amp;h the Next Actn to:</data>
            </data>
            <data name="ComboBox">
              <data name="Enabled">0</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">35193110</data>
              <data name="ID">1009</data>
              <data name="Text">Contact(s)</data>
              <data name="Controls">
                <data name="Edit">
                  <data name="Enabled">0</data>
                  <data name="Visible">1</data>
                  <data name="ParentID">35193110</data>
                  <data name="hWnd">2621498</data>
                  <data name="ID">1001</data>
                  <data name="Text">Contact(s)</data>
                </data>
              </data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">1</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">5641780</data>
              <data name="ID">123</data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">0</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">5308448</data>
              <data name="ID">1163</data>
              <data name="Text">RICK    </data>
            </data>
            <data name="Static">
              <data name="Enabled">1</data>
              <data name="Visible">0</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">1441814</data>
              <data name="ID">1164</data>
              <data name="Text">RICK    </data>
            </data>
            <data name="ListBox">
              <data name="Enabled">0</data>
              <data name="Visible">0</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">45681014</data>
              <data name="ID">0</data>
            </data>
            <data name="ListBox">
              <data name="Enabled">0</data>
              <data name="Visible">0</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">1311540</data>
              <data name="ID">0</data>
            </data>
            <data name="ListBox">
              <data name="Enabled">0</data>
              <data name="Visible">0</data>
              <data name="ParentID">5574210</data>
              <data name="hWnd">4396658</data>
              <data name="ID">0</data>
            </data>
          </data>
        </data>
        <data name="RadioButton">
          <data name="Enabled">1</data>
          <data name="Visible">1</data>
          <data name="ParentID">2952796</data>
          <data name="hWnd">2952792</data>
          <data name="ID">1</data>
          <data name="Text">Schedule</data>
        </data>
        <data name="Button">
          <data name="Enabled">1</data>
          <data name="Visible">1</data>
          <data name="ParentID">2952796</data>
          <data name="hWnd">2952782</data>
          <data name="ID">2</data>
          <data name="Text">Cancel</data>
        </data>
        <data name="Button">
          <data name="Enabled">0</data>
          <data name="Visible">0</data>
          <data name="ParentID">2952796</data>
          <data name="hWnd">2952776</data>
          <data name="ID">12321</data>
          <data name="Text">Apply</data>
        </data>
        <data name="Button">
          <data name="Enabled">1</data>
          <data name="Visible">0</data>
          <data name="ParentID">2952796</data>
          <data name="hWnd">2952774</data>
          <data name="ID">9</data>
          <data name="Text">Help</data>
        </data>
        <data name="SysTabControl32">
          <data name="Enabled">1</data>
          <data name="Visible">1</data>
          <data name="ParentID">2952796</data>
          <data name="hWnd">2952772</data>
          <data name="ID">12320</data>
        </data>
      </data>
    </data>
```

I'm looking for a function that parses this and returns a few fields each, for a few nodes as follows:

1. The ParentID and hWnd from the branch where data name ID is 1016
2. The ParentID and hWnd from the branch where data name ID is 1017
3. The ParentID and hWnd from the branch where data name ID is 1012
4. The ParentID and hWnd from the branch where data name ID is 1013

I have no code to supply for this portion of my project so far because nothing was workable enough to continue working on.
I've never needed to get this deep into XML programming before so some of the approaches are confusing.
I'm hoping some kind souls are able to whip this out without going through the days of anguish I went through, thanks!

Comment: My first suggestion would be to create an XDocument/XElement based parser, which would store a dictionary of values, i.e. property name to value, iterate once before any processing to build one, and use that to get the information you need. If you want me to be more specific and perhaps provide a code sample, please reduce your XML data to something that fits into StackOverflow question without the need to scroll. Specify how you want to be parsed, I am assuming you have some data structure that you want to map it to.

Comment: This xml data seems to represent an instanciated form with nested controls. You need an understanding of this particular xml metadata (xsd) before being able to tackle this problem. Parsing xml is not an issue. It's what to do with the object hierarchy that you will get out of parsing.

Comment: @Tarik, I know what to do with the control data once I have it, I was simply having a hard time using proper XML methods to access it.  I was considering parsing it as a text file (not the best approach but it would work) and move on if I could not succeed using better practices.

Comment: @Neolisk Thanks, if I can not get the solution from Mark to work, I'll try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```vb
Dim myXML As String = GetXmlFromSomewhere()
Dim xml = XElement.Parse(myXML)
Dim ids = { "1012", "1013", "1016", "1017" }
Dim result = 
    From d In xml...<data>
    Where d.@name = "ID" AndAlso ids.Contains(d.Value)
    Select
        ID = d.Value,
        ParentID = (From x In d.Parent.<data> Where x.@name = "ParentID" Select x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
        hWnd = (From x In d.Parent.<data> Where x.@name = "hWnd" Select x.Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I will try this today and follow up.  LINQ looks really cool and I have not heard of it until a few days ago.

Comment: @Mark I have a String variable named MyResult which contains this XML data.  I have a MsgBox(MyResult) immediately before I inserted your code. I modified the first line of your code to:  "Dim myXML As String = MyResult" in order to refer to my XML data.  I am not sure if that was the correct move, because when the "Dim xml = XElement.Load(myXML)" runs I encounter an error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Illegal characters in path."

Comment: Followup to my last comment which was getting too long to save:  Since MyResult is a string type and myXML is also sting type, I don't think there is a type issue - and no type mismatch error was issued.

Comment: @RickJohnson Oops, `XElement.Load` expects a file name - it should be `XElement.Parse`.

Comment: @Mark This is an absolutely brilliant and eloquent solution, thank you!  I'm still trying to work with the results - the value data is an 'anonymous' type and result is an IEnumerable.  I have not worked with these types yet, so I'm doing some studying before asking for additional assistance.

Comment: @RickJohnson Glad it works for you.  If you have a class you want to populate, you can use the [`New MyClass With {.ID = ...}`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx) syntax to populate that instead.  You can also use [`result.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to convert to a `List` - you can even wrap the query in parens and convert inline - `Dim result = (From d In...).ToList()`.  I would also recommend having [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) handy as a playground for testing these things out.